# Настройка vpn под линуксом

Tags: vpn, linux

Приветствую!

Я не могу настроить vpn под линуксом. Все, сколько знаю, ос перепробовал, все равно ошибка подключения! Но локалка работает. На акадо могу заходить, а в мир нет. Что мне сделать? Чтобы мой самсунг н-150+ смог заползать в мир? Или какую линукс мне лучше поставить?

Comment: Более конкретнее,что за ошибка? А,касательно выбора Linux зависит от предпочтений,для чего, и.т.д , и.т.п

Answer (score 1):

- [Технология VPN](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN)
- [OpenVPN HOWTO](http://lithium.opennet.ru/articles/openvpn/openvpn-howto.html)

Дополнительно ключевые слова для поиска: подробно о подключении к vpn, настройка vpn в Linux. Истина где-то рядом!

Answer (score 1):

> [vpnpptp](http://code.google.com/p/vpnpptp/) - это простая в использовании и конфигурировании программа для VPN-соединений через PPTP, через L2TP и через OpenL2TP для Linux. Она написана на FreePascal с использованием Shell скриптов.